# Test en jest + superset para comprobar si Playground de GraphQL (web) carga

Tags: nodejs, express, test, graphql, jest

Tengo el siguiente **test en jest + supertest** para probar si el **Playground de GraphQL carga** (web):

```
/**
 *  @test   'GraphQL Playground loads'
 */
test( 'GraphQL Playground loads', async() => {

    const response: Response = await request( app ).get( '/graphql' )

    expect( response.status ).toBe( 200 )
    expect( response.text ).toMatch( 'GraphQL Playground' )

})
```

Pero por alguna razón el **test no pasa la 1ra prueba**:

```
Expected: 200
Received: 400
```

Al probar **sólo con la 2da**:

```
Expected substring: "GraphQL Playground"
Received string:    "GET query missing."
```

Lo raro es que **la página si carga** y Morgan en consola dice:
`GET /graphql 200`

**Alguna idea?**

Answer (score 0):

Después de intentar algunas cosas lo **solucioné** enviando la cabecera:

```
const response: Response = await request( app )
    .get( '/graphql' )
    .accept( 'text/html' )
;
```